# Angular JS : Error: Unexpected request: GET templates/login.html

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-mock

I am getting the following error when executing jasmine test cases.

> Error: Unexpected request: GET templates/login.html No more request
>   expected
>       at $httpBackend (D:/Src/Rep/myapp/js/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1244:9)
>       at sendReq (D:/Src/Rep/myapp/js/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js:10515:9)
>       at serverRequest (D:/Src/Rep/myapp/js/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js:10222:16)
>       at processQueue (D:/Src/Rep/myapp/js/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js:14745:28)
>       at D:/Src/Rep/myapp/js/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js:14761:27
>       at Scope.$eval (D:/Src/Rep/myapp/js/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js:15989:28)
>       at Scope.$digest (D:/Src/Rep/myapp/js/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js:15800:31)
>       at ChildScope.$apply (D:/Src/Rep/myapp/js/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js:16097:24)
>       at UserContext. (D:/Src/Rep/myapp/tests/controllers/myController-test.js:128:15)
>       at Object.invoke (D:/Src/Rep/myapp/js/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js:4478:17) Error:
>   Declaration Location
>       at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (D:/Src/Rep/myapp/js/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2409:25)
>       at Suite. (D:/Src/Rep/myapp/tests/controllers/myController-test.js:118:73)
>       at D:/Src/Rep/myapp/tests/controllers/myController-test.js:1:1

I don't understand what does this error means.
I tried to use

```
$httpBackend.whenGET("/templates/login.html").passThrough();
```

as well as

```
  $httpBackend.when('GET', 'templates/login.html')
            .respond(200, '');
```

in my code but no luck.

Can someone please suggest?

Comment: i guess you are running you application on server and not just running index.html from browser

Comment: Hi @AbhishekAnand I am using karma to run test cases and using WebStorm editor

Comment: try this $httpBackend.whenGET(/^\/templates\//).passThrough();

Comment: Hi @AnkitPandey, tried it at the very first line of my testcase, but no luck. I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, adding following line at the start of my test case worked for me. `$httpBackend.whenGET(/templates/).respond(200, '');`

**Example:**

```
it('Validate something', inject(function(SomeService) {
    $httpBackend.whenGET(/templates/).respond(200, '');
    .......
    .......
}));
```